# Http file download wget command line

Tags: windows, wget

I am downloading one http file using Wget command line in windows, but its not downloading, Please can any body assist me . Thanks

```
C:\Users\ICCSIR4\Downloads>wget --user=myuser --ask-password https://dds.cr.usg
s.gov/ltaauth//sno18/ops/l1/2017/151/043/LC81510432017067LGN00.tar.gz?id=ieden9r
gsjhil5pmr6050oopf6&iid=LC81510432017067LGN00&did=305822397&ver=production
Password for user 'shouvik':
--2017-03-11 14:14:58--  https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/ltaauth//sno18/ops/l1/2017/151/
043/LC81510432017067LGN00.tar.gz?id=ieden9rgsjhil5pmr6050oopf6
Resolving dds.cr.usgs.gov (dds.cr.usgs.gov)... 152.61.133.66, 152.61.133.67
Connecting to dds.cr.usgs.gov (dds.cr.usgs.gov)|152.61.133.66|:443... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-03-11 14:15:05 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

'iid' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'did' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclose your URL with doublequotes.

Comment: Thank you. can i get a example ?

Comment: wget --user=myuser --ask-password "https://dds.cr.usg
s.gov/ltaauth//sno18/ops/l1/2017/151/043/LC81510432017067LGN00.tar.gz?id=ieden9r
gsjhil5pmr6050oopf6&iid=LC81510432017067LGN00&did=305822397&ver=production"